# "Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!" - Kile jumps straight to my .aux file

Tags: errors, pdftex, auxiliary-files, todonotes

As stated in the question, trying to produce a pdf, results in the above error, and Kile (my editor of choice) opens a new tab with the `aux` file. If I look at `myfile.log`, it ends with the following (and 3400 lines above it):

```
l.1185 \@
     LN{932}{15}
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m {}
l.1186 \@
         LN{933}{15}
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 17820 strings out of 493315
 299733 string characters out of 6145893
 408971 words of memory out of 5000000
 20928 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 12592 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 63i,3n,57p,974b,205s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

**So how do I make sense of that?** It seems like the `spacefactor` is an error that I can ignore (even though it shows up 326 times), and probably is related to some macros or self defined commands (in the template) beyond my control. At last I can't think of anything I have done, related to math mode, that I have tone 326 times. **What else can the log file tell me?**

**Or, how do I actually boil it down to a minimal example, that I could share?** This specific error message shows up quite a few times, but most times its either something very `beamer` specific (which I am not using), points towards some issues where files are locked, or the user has not rights to write a certain file (should also be no problem in my case) or dies without an answer.

Problem is, the whole thing is occurring in an 800 line document, that used to compile without problems (that is, no errors that put everything to a halt), until I put in a table. But if I put the table into a minimal example (see below), it works, but if I comment out the table in my original document, it still fails. So, it is not the table!?

**Then what else could it be? How do I pinpoint the input where it all starts to go wrong?**

The `aux` file that gets opened has the cursor at a line saying the following:

```
\@writefile{tdo}{\contentsline {todo}{nur ganz grobe Idee. Falls Sinnvoll, koennte ich daf\GenericError  {(inputenc)                }{Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined\MessageBreak in inputencoding `utf8'}{See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.}{You need to provide a definition with \def 1 ${}\def \begingroup \let \reserved@d =\bgroup \def \let \reserved@d =*\def \par }\def \begingroup \let \reserved@d =\bgroup \def \let \reserved@d =*\def \par }\def \begingroup \let \reserved@d =\bgroup \def \let \reserved@d =*\def \par }\def \begingroup \let \reserved@d =\bgroup \def \let \reserved@d =*\def \par
```

OK, so it has issues with encoding, and I have some German words with stuff like **ü** and **ß** in them, but I have had those letters in there from the beginning, and those errors I could always ignore. And the rest is not very readable to me.

---

**Example**

Using the `copernicus` template from [linked here](http://www.hydrology-and-earth-system-sciences.net/for_authors/manuscript_preparation.html)

```
\documentclass[hess]{copernicus}%, manuscript]{copernicus}
%% \usepackage commands included in the copernicus.cls:
%\usepackage[german, english]{babel}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{supertabular}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{rotating}


\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

test 


%%% TWO-COLUMN TABLE
%
%t
\begin{table*}[t]
  \caption{This is a table
  \todo[inline]{some fixme notes about this table}
  }
%\begin{tabular}{column = l c c c c}
  %Somehow, the above does not work, even though the template specifies it. But the standard solution below works. 
\begin{tabular}{l | c c c c c c}
Location  &  Average    &   Average    & Average   & Average    &  Average  & Average   \\

\tophline
xxx  &  yyy  &  yyy & yyy  & yyy & yyy & yyy   \\
xxx &  yyy  &  yyy & yyy  &  yyy &  yyy & yyy \\
% 
% 
% \middlehline
% 
% \bottomhline
\end{tabular}
\belowtable{} % Table Footnotes
\label{Result_table}
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

works.

**EDIT**
I have played around a bit with deleting the `aux` file, and I can somewhat get it to compile. Seems like this line:

```
xx    & SGI, SPI and SRSI  &  SGI and SPI  &  SGI &  SGI and SRSI  &  SRSI  &  SRSI and SPI  \\
```

is the one causing it to fail. However, when I put it into the example above, it does not cause any issues. How can a single line that seems to be quite "normal" cause a whole document to fail?

**EDIT2**
Here is the output of `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
copernicus.cls    2016/01/22 8.09 Copernicus papers
fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
copernicus.cfg
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
   fleqn.clo    1998/08/17 v1.1c Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ts1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2013/05/16 v3.9f The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
tabularx.sty    1999/01/07 v2.07 `tabularx' package (DPC)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
   color.sty    1999/02/16
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
dvipsnam.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  cancel.sty    2000/03/12 v2.1 Cancel math terms
multirow.sty    
supertabular.sty    2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment
 caption.sty    2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
  natbib.sty    2006/09/06 7.4a (PWD)
rotating.sty    2009/03/28 v2.16a rotated objects in LaTeX
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  lineno.sty    2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
   times.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
  pifont.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Pi font support (SPQR) 
    upzd.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for U/pzd.
    upsy.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for U/psy.
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
  hdvips.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for dvips
 pdfmark.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref definitions for pdfmark specials
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
todonotes.sty    2012/07/25
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
   t1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
   t1phv.fd    2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for T1/phv.
graphics/pic1.jpeg
graphics/pic2.png
graphics/....png
draft.bbl
 ***********
```

System is: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/TeX Live for SUSE Linux) (format=latex 2016.6.17)  6 JUL 2016 15:56`

I just ran my list and the list in the accepted answer trough a comparison, and it seems that in almost all cases, a different (older) date is quoted on Opensuse, and also, often, older versions. But in most cases, it only seems to be minor version differences. I would assume that a large and current distro, such as Opensuse ships a working texlive.

Comment: Don't put \todo in a \caption argument. And delete your aux-file before recompiling. If you still get errors: Don't ignore them, even if if the result looks correct, correct them all starting with the first.

Comment: Deleting the aux file still results in no pdf, but this time I have `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [11
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\reserved@a ->\def \reserved@a 
                               *{\@refstar }\reserved@a 
l.632 
      
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.` before it. Seems quite different. And why no `\todo`? in captions? That used to never be an issue.

Comment: The table is probably interacting badly with something else in the document. Make a copy of your document and start commenting out blocks of code and recompiling. Reduce it as far as you can (while preserving the error) and you will have a minimal example.

Comment: I renamed the file, and compiled it again (Latex, Bibtex, Latex, Pdflatex) and it worked. Put in the table again, still worked. Put in this line:  ` xx    & SGI, SPI and SRSI  &SGI and SPI  &  SGI &  SGI and SRSI  &  SRSI  &  SRSI and SPI  \\ `  as second line in table, fails. Remove it, works again.

Comment: Sorry I was distracted: Delete beside the aux also the lot and lof file. The argument of \caption is written to external files, \todo is a fragile command, it can break -- even more if you are using umlauts in the todo text. So avoid to use it in caption.

Comment: I dont get lot and lof files. Only aux, bbl, blg and dvi (and pdf. Sometimes…). The `\todo` is supposed to get removed in the final version anyways, so if I loose some umlauts, I dont really care, but can it really break the whole document? so far, it seemed to work, with umlauts in captions.

Comment: God, I'm too tired. Delete the tdo. And check the todo starting with "*nur ganz grobe Idee. Falls Sinnvoll, koennte ich daf*", it contains probably some problematic accent or something like this.

Comment: The todo in question did indeed contain an umlaut, but those normally just fail without causing issues. I'm still not convinced that it is the todonotes, but I'll move them out of captions, just to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here, I think.

First, your given message `l.1185 \@ ... N{932}{15}` comes usualy from package `lineno` you didn't mention in your problem description.

I guess you activated an option for class `copernicus` to get a numbered line output?  If that is true and you changed the option to be unnumbered you should delete file `.aux` before recompiling to avoid the given message ...

Second, package `caption` gives a warning, that `copernicus` is an unsupported class.  That can be causing unexspected errors or warnings!

Third, you are using an file with utf-8 encoding.  Then you can add the german umlauts äöüÄÖÜ and the eszet ß **without** using the escaped version of adding umlauts for ascii text for LaTeX!

Fourth, do not call `\todo` inside a caption. You can add an `\todo` after closing the caption (I showed in the following MWE, including correct, working umlauts) or after the place where you refered to the table ...

Fiths, please check with adding `\listfiles` as first line in your TeX code, if your TeX distribution is up to date.  Then you get a list of used packages and version numbers at the end of the `log` file after compiling.  Add this list please to your question.  I guess, there are some packages outdated on your system ...

MWE (see new `\todo` marked with `<====================`):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[hess]{copernicus}%, manuscript]{copernicus}
%% \usepackage commands included in the copernicus.cls:
%\usepackage[german, english]{babel}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{supertabular}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{rotating}


\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

test 


%%% TWO-COLUMN TABLE
%
%t
\begin{table*}[t]
  \caption{This is a table
% \todo[inline]{some fixme notes about this table}
  }
  \todo[inline]{some fixme notes about this table äöüßÄÖÜ} % <============================
%\begin{tabular}{column = l c c c c}
  %Somehow, the above does not work, even though the template specifies it. But the standard solution below works. 
\begin{tabular}{l | c c c c c c}
Location  &  Average    &   Average    & Average   & Average    &  Average  & Average   \\

\tophline
xxx  &  yyy  &  yyy & yyy  & yyy & yyy & yyy   \\
xxx &  yyy  &  yyy & yyy  &  yyy &  yyy & yyy \\
% 
% 
% \middlehline
% 
% \bottomhline
\end{tabular}
\belowtable{} % Table Footnotes
\label{Result_table}
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

compiled with no errors to:

[image]

and the returned list file with an current MiKTeX 2.9:

```
 *File List*
copernicus.cls    2016/01/22 8.09 Copernicus papers
fixltx2e.sty    2015/06/22 v2.0b fixes to LaTeX (obsolete)
copernicus.cfg
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
   fleqn.clo    2015/03/31 v1.1i Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ts1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
tabularx.sty    2016/02/03 v2.11 `tabularx' package (DPC)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/06/02 v1.0s Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/06/17 v0.06h Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   color.sty    1999/02/16
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amsmath.sty    2016/03/10 v2.15b AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 accents.sty    2006/05/12 v1.3 Math Accent Tools
  cancel.sty    2013/04/12 v2.2 Cancel math terms
multirow.sty    
supertabular.sty    2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment
algorithmic.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithmic'
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
algorithm.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environment
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
 caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
subfloat.sty    2003/08/21 version 2.14
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
rotating.sty    2016/05/22 v2.16c rotated objects in LaTeX
  lineno.sty    2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
   times.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
  pifont.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Pi font support (SPQR) 
    upzd.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for U/pzd.
    upsy.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for U/psy.
hyperref.sty    2016/05/21 v6.83p Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2016/05/21 v6.83p Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
 hpdftex.def    2016/05/21 v6.83p Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
todonotes.sty    2012/07/25
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
   t1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
   t1phv.fd    2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for T1/phv.
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
 ***********
```

At last just a remark to your errors you get "you can omit" ... I'm sure that one or more of theese errors are causing your problems in compiling your document.  It is very important that you correct all errors in your document, and start allways with the first, correct it, recompile and check the next **first** error.  Please see, that the **first** error can causing the next errors, and theese errors do vanish if you correct the first one!

**Update:**

Your TeX distribution TeX Live 2013 is very old. The current one is TeX Live 2016!  TeX/LaTeX is continuining developed, therefore it is **important to keep your distribution up-to-date**! The change of one package can result errors in other packages.  For example is package `fixltx2` since 2016 obsolete ...

Please update your TeX distribution to get rid off the errors you have ...

Package `todonotes` is an older package, therefore command `\todo` is **no robust** command.  That means, it is fragile, and it can **sometimes** result with an error.  Command `\todo` was designed 2012 to be added as own command into an paragraph or an environment, but **not as part** of another command, as you tried with your combination `\caption{...\todo{...}}`.

So please use `\todo` in the way it is desiged ...  And sorry, I do not have a link for you, it is just my knowledge (from looking inside the code of `todonotes`).

Comment: That's very helpful! some comments: Yes, `lineno` is used. I didn't specify it, since it is in the `copernicus.cls` somwhere, as is `caption`. Didn't mention those, since their use is beyond my control. I figured a publisher would know what they do… I dont know what's happening with utf8, since it gets ignored. I'm mostly writing in english, so that is not an issue. The `todo` part is interesting. Don't understand why (since it works, mostly), but I guess changing wont hurt. Do you have any link on that issue, since it is not in the docs for todonotes?

Comment: That's quite weird that OpenSuse chose to ship such an old version of texlive, while everything else in the distro is way to cutting edge and unstable. Oh well, unless I go back to fedora, I just have to live with it, but I'd rather have something stable. But anyways: Thanks for the info about `\todo`. I wouldn't call 2012 old, but thanks for checking its code! I have now changed their positions, and fixed my other errors, and now I'm down to 0 to 2 errors, which is quite OK for 20p document, and for an "old" version of texlive.